# Storing abstract classes in an arraylist

Tags: java, android, inheritance, arraylist, abstract

So, I am making an android app with java and have the following classes.

My problem is that when I create accounts in the app lets say new CheckingAccount(111, 111) and new SavingsAccount(222, 222), and then try to all them in another class using CreateAccountActivity.getAccountNumberID(0) and get the following error

```
   Process: bankapp, PID: 4918
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
   ComponentInfo{bankapp/bankapp.EditAccountActivity}:
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
      Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
         at bankapp.CreateAccountActivity.getAccountNumberID(CreateAccountActivity.java:131)
         at bankapp.EditAccountActivity.onCreate(EditAccountActivity.java:37)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

CreateAccountActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    public static ArrayList<BankAccount> aAccount = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

EditText accountNumberTV, initialBalanceTV;
String accountType;
Context context = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);



    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.accountTypeSpinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Checking");
    categories.add("Savings");
    categories.add("Credit");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    final Button SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createNewAccountButton);
    SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            accountNumberTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountNumberView);
            accountNumberTV.setTransformationMethod(null);

            initialBalanceTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.initialBalanceView)

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    accountType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void CreateAccountButton(View view) {
    accountNumberTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountNumberView);
    accountNumberTV.setTransformationMethod(null);

    initialBalanceTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.initialBalanceView);


    String acctIDString = accountNumberTV.getText().toString();
    int acctID=Integer.parseInt(acctIDString);

    String initialBalanceString = initialBalanceTV.getText().toString();
    double initialBalance=Float.parseFloat(initialBalanceString);
    //bd.setUserInfo(1,newName, newAddress, context);

    switch(accountType) {
        case "Checking":

            aAccount.add(new CheckingAccount(acctID, initialBalance));
            break;
        case "Savings":

            aAccount.add(new SavingsAccount(acctID, initialBalance));
            break;
        case "Credit":
            // code block
            break;
    }

}
static public int getAccountNumberID (int x){
    return aAccount.get(x).getAcctID();
}
static public int getArraySize(){
  return aAccount.size();
}

public double getAccountBalance(int x){
    return aAccount.get(x).getCurrentBalance();
  }
}
```

BankAccount.java

```
public abstract class BankAccount {
private final int acctID;
double acctBalance = 0;
public BankAccount checking;
public BankAccount savings;
public BankAccount credit;

public BankAccount (int Id, double balance){
    this.acctID = Id;
    this.acctBalance = balance;
}


public void deposit (double amount){
    acctBalance = acctBalance + amount;
    //System.out.println(acctBalance);
}

public boolean withdraw (double amount){
    if(acctBalance<amount){
        //System.out.println("There are insufficient funds.");
        return false;
    } else
        acctBalance = acctBalance - amount;
    System.out.println(acctBalance);
    return true;
}

double balance (BankAccount acctID) {
    return acctBalance;
}

public double getCurrentBalance(){
    return acctBalance;
}

public int getAcctID () {
    return acctID;
}


public static boolean transfer (double amount, BankAccount fromAccount, BankAccount toAccount) {
    if (fromAccount.acctBalance > amount){
        fromAccount.acctBalance = fromAccount.acctBalance - amount;
        toAccount.acctBalance = toAccount.acctBalance + amount;
        //System.out.println(fromAccount.acctBalance);
        //System.out.println(toAccount.acctBalance);
        return true;
    } else
        //System.err.println("Insufficient funds");
    return false;
}

}
```

CheckingAccount.java

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
public BankAccount checking;

public CheckingAccount(int Id, double balance) {
    super(Id, balance);
}

public void deposit (double amount)
{
    super.deposit(amount);
}
}
```

SavingsAccount.java

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{
public BankAccount savings;
public SavingsAccount(int Id, double balance) {
    super(Id, balance);
}
public void deposit (double amount)
{
    super.deposit(amount);
}
}
```

EditAccount.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


 public class EditAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

//ArrayList<BankAccount> aAccount2=CreateAccountActivity.getList();
Context context = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editaccount);
    int arraysize = CreateAccountActivity.getArraySize();


    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectAccountSpinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // (2) create a simple static list of strings
    List<Integer> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<>();
    //spinnerArray.add(1);
    //spinnerArray.add(aAccount2.get(0).getAcctID());
    //spinnerArray.add(aAccount2.get(1).getAcctID());
    spinnerArray.add(CreateAccountActivity.getAccountNumberID(0));
    spinnerArray.add(CreateAccountActivity.getAccountNumberID(1));
    int i = 0;

  /*  do{

        spinnerArray.add(CreateAccountActivity.getAccountNumberID(i));
        i++;
    }while (i<2);
   */

    // (3) create an adapter from the list
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            spinnerArray
    );

 //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 // (4) set the adapter on the spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using static in conjugation with an instance variable of an activity doesn't work. You can solve your task with ViewModels. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
    // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

    MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    model.getAccounts()
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel { 
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        // return sth.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this totally worked. Thank you so much, you saved my life. Why on earth has this not been taught to me before. My education may be free but boy is in not good.